# A better way to get keyboard input using Windows API?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, keyboard

I am currently using c++ and the windows API to create a program that requires user input from the keyboard.

My current solution is working, but I wanted to ask if there is a better way to achieve what I am trying to do.

Current solution:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    switch (message){
    case WM_CHAR:
        switch (wParam) {
        case 119:
            std::cout << "W" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 97:
            std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 115:
            std::cout << "S" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 100:
            std::cout << "D" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        break;
    return 0;
}
```

If I want to get every key on the keyboard, I will have to make a case for each key. Is there a better way?

Also, is there any reference online where I can get the code for each key?

Edit: I want to implement logic for each individual key. Should have mentioned that at the start, my apologies.

Thank you

Comment: Those look like ASCII codes. E.g. `97` == `'a'`.

Comment: Yes there is a better way, use a table. And anway never use "magic numbers", here instead of `119` you should write `'w'`, instead of `97` you should write `'a'` etc. Learn what the [ASCII code](http://www.asciitable.com/) is. And before fiddling with withe win32 api you should learn the C language.

Comment: Do you want to do the same thing, only with a different character, in each case?

Comment: @molbdnilo I need to do a different thing with each key

Comment: A call to [`DefWindowProc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/using-window-procedures) is missing.

Comment: Since you are asking about your solution rather than the problem you are trying to solve, I cannot be sure, but it looks like you'll be throwing this code away soon. W/A/S/D sounds like you are trying to implement input to control game state. In that case you shouldn't be using character messages at all, and go with keyboard messages instead. And if you are serious about this, you probably want to use a different solution altogether (e.g. XInput or DirectInput).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you literally just wanted to print every key, [ASCII table being mapped directly in this case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-char), the obvious is to have this inside `case WM_CHAR:`, instead of the whole second `switch`:

```
std::wcout << static_cast<wchar_t>(wParam) << std::endl;
```

In case you want to be able to define a separate, specific handler logic for each key, perhaps the following example would be a better pattern, as it would simplify the logic of your `WndProc()`, and add a level of indirection, enabling you to treat the handlers themselves as first-class objects:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <map>

#include <Windows.h>

std::map<uint32_t, std::function<void()>> gKeyCallback;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CHAR:
        auto mapIter = gKeyCallback.find(static_cast<uint32_t>(wParam));
        if (mapIter != gKeyCallback.end())
            mapIter->second();
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    gKeyCallback['W'] = [] {std::cout << "Handler for 'W'" << std::endl; };
    gKeyCallback['A'] = [] {std::cout << "Handler for 'A'" << std::endl; };
    gKeyCallback['S'] = [] {std::cout << "Handler for 'S'" << std::endl; };
    gKeyCallback['D'] = [] {std::cout << "Handler for 'D'" << std::endl; };

    return 0;
}
```

The idea consists of holding a mapping container, enabling to fetch the appropriate handler callback function for each given key. You can change the prototype to suit your needs. The [*lambda expression*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) notation is being used to make initialization of each key handler less strenuous on the eyes readable and easier to maintain later on:

This line:

```
std::map<uint32_t, std::function<void()>> gKeyCallback;
```

defines the mapping container (a.k.a. *a dictionary*) object. It is of [type `std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), and here it denotes a mapping from type `uint32_t` to the handler callback function type -- currently being a uniform `void()` callback.

What this line does:

```
gKeyCallback['W'] = [] {std::cout << "Handler for 'W'" << std::endl; };
```

is map key value `119` (ASCII value of `'W'`) to the specific logic desired for it, specified inside the `{}` (*curly braces*). The key syntactic element for this here is the `[]`. [Here you can read all about how to use this *lambda expression* syntax](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Note: This is definitely not a recommendation for using global variables (`gKeyCallback`), it's just there for complete code example simplicity.

Comment: I actually need to implement some logic for each individual key, so I think they second option will work for me. I don't fully understand the solution though. I will try to look through it and figure it out.

Comment: @user3702643 I hear you, thought it might be the case. Can you tell me what's the parts that are hard to understand so I can edit the answer to improve?

Comment: Explaining this line std::map<uint32_t, std::function<void()>> gKeyCallback; and 
    gKeyCallback[119] = [] {std::cout << "Handler for 'W'" << std::endl; }; would be very helpful. For the second line that I mentioned, is that how I can implement my own logic for each key? Thank you!

Comment: @user3702643  I've added specific explanations to the answer just now for what you have commented about. Also, that's a positive answer to you question *" is that how I can implement my own logic for each key?".*